# Getting failure while using POST operation in node.js using "request" module

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, httprequest, jasmine-node

I am using node js, jasmine framework for my API automation testing. I have a POST operation. I use npm-request to do the operation.

My code in my test case is below

```
describe('Verification of BS_057_LockDN',()=>{

    it('Verify success response for BS_057_LockDN',function(done){
        var path=require('path');
        let inputJson=require(path.resolve('./inputRequests/lockDNInput.json'));
        let endpoint=require(path.resolve('./config/endpointLockDN.json'));

        const fetch=require('node-fetch');

        let baseUrl=endpoint.url;
        let apikey=endpoint.apikey;

    let fullUrlWithQueryParameters= baseUrl + "?apikey=" + apikey

        console.log(fullUrlWithQueryParameters);
        console.log(inputJson);
        console.log("test");


        var request = require('request');

     request.post(fullUrlWithQueryParameters,inputJson,
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('ew fu----------------------------------------------')
        if (error) 
            {

                console.log(error);
                return done();
            }
            console.log('first');
            console.log('HTTP STATUS CODE:'+ response.statusCode);
            console.log('second');
            console.log(body);
            expect(body).not.toBeUndefined();
            expect(body.Header.MsgType_T).toBe('RESPONSE');
            done();
    }
);

    },1000*60*60)


})
```

When I run this test case, I get the below error

```
Failures:
1) Verification of BS_057_LockDN Verify success response for BS_057_LockDN
  Message:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'MsgType_T' of undefined
  Stack:
        at <Jasmine>
        at Request._callback (F:\johny\node_from_home\spec\BS_057_LockDN.spec.js:44:32)
        at Request.self.callback (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\request\request.js:1157:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\request\request.js:1079:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
        at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'MsgType_T' of undefined
  Stack:
        at <Jasmine>
        at Request._callback (F:\johny\node_from_home\spec\BS_057_LockDN.spec.js:44:32)
        at Request.self.callback (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\request\request.js:1157:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\request\request.js:1079:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
        at emitNone (events.js:111:20)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 60.348 seconds
Randomized with seed 13965 (jasmine --random=true --seed=13965)
```

I am not sure why I am getting undefined for my POST operation. Am I using the correct method?

I have attached the SOAP ui request and response for the same.[image]

Answer (score 0):

your request seems to be OK. but you are try to read data from undefined field in the body

```
expect(body.Header.MsgType_T).toBe('RESPONSE');
```

here "Header" is not exist in the body.

Comment: thanks..But i have a field like "body.Header.MsgType_T". What I am asking is, In body I am not receiving any response

Comment: try like this:
     var request = require('request');
    request.post({
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
  url:     <your URL>,
  body:    <req_body in json>
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});

Comment: and also print your url and post data and check whether it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

never do two-step object accessing without checking it.

here you're accessing "body.Header.MsgType_T" in "expect(body.Header.MsgType_T).toBe('RESPONSE');" without checking whether "body.Header" exists or not.

hope this helps..

Comment: thanks..But i have a field like "body.Header.MsgType_T". What I am asking is, In body I am not receiving any response